# How to add image to edge in d3 graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graph-theory

Consider force-directed graph (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642).

Here we add links:

```
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(json.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");
```

The question is: how to add some image to the edge (to link), and place it into the center of the line?

This one doesn't work:

```
    link.append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", "some.png")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x)/2; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y)/2; })
    .attr("width", 24)
    .attr("height", 24);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're appending the `image` element to a `line` element -- it won't show this way. You need to append it either to the top-level `svg` element or a `g` element. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/8935723) is an example that does that.